# ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking in dylib built for iOS, file 'Frameworks/TitaniumKit.framework/TitaniumKit' for architecture arm64

Tags: javascript, ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am getting this error when I am trying to build my appcelerator app for ios

```
ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking in dylib built for iOS, file 'Frameworks/TitaniumKit.framework/TitaniumKit' for architecture arm64
```

I already tried to find a way to set the "excluded architectures" on the appcelerator configs but it seems not be possible.

[image]

Comment: I'm also having this, did you manage to build?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to properly compile after setting the configuration for excluded architectures by adding an override within the module.xcconfig file of a module in use on my project.

I added the following lines:

```
EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphoneos*] = x86_64
EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*] = arm64
ARCHS[sdk=iphoneos*] = arm64
ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*] = x86_64
VALID_ARCHS[sdk=iphoneos*] = arm64
VALID_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*] = x86_64
```

The location of the stored modules can be found at:

```
/Users/{user}/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this code in **module.xconfig** inside your affected module folder:

```
VALIDATE_WORKSPACE = YES
```